# MySQL: How to count data row that resulted from GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Based on my questions above. I want to count the row data that display based on a query that I created. Below is the query and result:

1. query

   ```
   SELECT MONTHNAME(start_date) AS month, 
          YEAR(start_date) AS year, 
          SUM(training_hour) AS man_hours
    FROM wtr_training_record 
    WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2022-02-28' AND '2022-03-02'
    GROUP BY MONTH(start_date)
   ```
2. Result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvcK9.png)

From the results, I want to add another Column whose name 'total_months'. SO in this case, the total months is 2 (which are February and March). Can anyone know how to do this? What I Know is using COUNT. But don't know how to handle with it

Comment: Your query with sql mode only_full_group_by enabled, it should produce an error. As per the question add in the select condition ...count(distinct MONTHNAME(start_date)),the group by clause  should be  `MONTHNAME(start_date),YEAR(start_date)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this query:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(start_date) AS month, 
       YEAR(start_date) AS year, 
       SUM(training_hour) AS man_hours, 
       count(month) AS total_months 
FROM wtr_training_record 
WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2022-02-28' AND '2022-03-02' 
GROUP BY MONTH(start_date)
```

Comment: Unknown column month

Comment: When the date is '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28', the results for total_months is 28. Should be 1 right? because only February is displayed

Comment: can change it to `count(distinct month(start_date))` in order to count February once instead for each row